# No Staking Rewards on MainNet

Tags: solana-program

Would you please advise why I'm not getting rewards for my transaction -> https://solanabeach.io/address/dcq4kMC4Puus6NZNHfuzo1r54wqhff3SUUTsWFTa9DD/transactions

I do not see any rewards:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you staked the smallest possible value of SOL (1 * 10^-9). You probably haven't earned any rewards on this staked amount.

Comment: This is the right answer -- you'll only see rewards once your staked amount gets at least 1 lamport. If you're staking 1 lamport, this will take years.